# Test Django url 'name' is correct url

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-urls, django-unittest

I think what I'm trying to is self evident:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
]
```

test.py

```
def test_home_page_view_name_uses_correct_url(self):
    name = self.client.get(reverse('home_page'))
    path = self.client.get('/')

    self.assertEqual(name, path)
```

But I get this error:

```
AssertionError: <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
             != <HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

How can I test this correctly?

Comment: You want to test that the URL is the same or you want to test that your '/' URL is rendering a certain view/template?

Comment: I would recommend the testing goat free e-book and the chapter on unit testing your home page: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_unit_test_first_view.html

Comment: I guess the same view. I want to make sure that when I use the name, the path is the same as using the hardcoded path

Comment: I just finished that book. He didn't cover that specifically. Maybe it isn't necessary? @dfundako

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any reason to involve the client here.

```
name = reverse('home_page')
path = '/'
```

self.assertEqual(name, path)

Comment: Of course, it was so simple I couldn't think of it. Thanks!